# Expected value of coin tossed twice

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

Here's the problem:

A (Laplace) coin with sides $0$ and $1$ is tossed twice, each time independently from the other. Let

$f:=$ maximum of both results

$g:=$ sum of both results.

What is the expected value and variance of $f$ and $g$?

I think $E[g]=2*\frac{1}{4} + 1*\frac{1}{2}+0*\frac{1}{2}+0*\frac{1}{4}=1$, but I'm not sure how to go about calculating the rest. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: For those (like me) who might wonder what a "Laplace coin" might be -- it looks like it's another term for "fair coin".

Answer (score 2):

Only two coins, so it's easy to see all combinations, each with 1/4 probability:

```
toss  f  g
00    0  0   
01    1  1
10    1  1
11    1  2
```

Expected value of random variable $X$ denoted as $E[X]$ is a sum of results, multiplied by their probabilities. I.e.,

$E[g] = \frac{1}{4}*0+\frac{1}{4}*1+\frac{1}{4}*1+\frac{1}{4}*2$

Now, variance is

$E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$

I believe it is an easy task to go from these definitions to the answer of your question.